Sleep() function. seems to interfere with \b and \r command
C++ beginner here, so please excuse me if this is caused by something simple I'm overlooking.
I was learning how to use the \b and \r commands. In my test program, they seem to run just fine, but when I try to combine a line of the Sleep() function in this code, the \b and \r turn ineffective, as if they aren't there.
Any and every input is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
code without Sleep():
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h> //for the sleep() fn
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"hello!";
    cout<<"\rBye!!!";
}

this outputs(bye!!!), which means my \r works as expected.
if i add a Sleep(1000) after the hello output line, like this:
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"hello!";
    Sleep(1000);
    cout<<"\rBye!!!";
}


the output now is:
hello!
Bye!!!
there is a 1-second delay, but the "bye!!!" doesn't get printed in place of the hello, like I want it to.

What if you make it cout<<"\rBye!!!\n"; instead?

Because Sleep can cause flushing the cout buffer and \r can't have effect after the flush on some terminals.

C++ does not say anything about how \b and \r work. When you write cout << "\r"; all C++ says is that the \r character will be sent to the standard output stream. What that does to your console has nothing at all to do with C++. The behaviour that you are seeing is because of the way that the Windows console works.

Using Visual Studio 2022 it works just fine.

This is console dependent.  Some consoles ignore '\r' and react only to '\n'.  Other consoles or terminals will actually move the carriage to the beginning of the line.  Some consoles will move the carriage all the way to the left and then move to the next line. There is no universal standard; there hasn't been since the Teletype and probably won't be.
